# Suppress stacked bar chart label if less than n

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have data with a lot of values. When plotting a percentage, a lot of values show up in 0%, which are then displayed in a plot. I do not want to include labels which are less than **0%** or **n%**.

This is the code that I use to produce the output

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.random.rand(5,10)
data = 10 + data*10
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))


ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%.0f%%', label_type='center')
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), loc='upper left')
```

I know that I can do what I need using this

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
for c in ax.containers:
    labels = [v if v > 12 else "" for v in c.datavalues]    
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type="center")
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), loc='upper left')
```

This way I can suppress values less than 12, but how can I limit amount of decimals which will be shown in label like this `fmt='%.0f%%'` ?

Comment: `labels = [f"{v:.0f}" if v > 12 else "" for v in c.datavalues]`

Comment: Thanks! You should post it as an answer so I can accept as a solution